# Remember me cookie with code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how to add in a remember me functionality into my script with code igniter. Here's what I"m attempting to do with the checkbox. I'm getting a syntax error for the if statment. Am I not using it correctly?

```
<?php echo form_label(form_checkbox( 'remember', 1, if (isset($this->input->cookie('xtrcook'))) { TRUE } ) . ' Auto-login in future.', 'remember' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error because you're trying to pass this as an argument:

```
if (isset($this->input->cookie('xtrcook'))) { TRUE }
```

That's not how expressions work in PHP. You want this to be `TRUE` is the `xtrcook` cookie is set, so just pass in this:

```
isset($this->input->cookie('xtrcook'))
```

Actually, `$this->input->cookie()` returns either the cookie value or `FALSE`, and both are always "set" so `isset()` is not appropriate here, you can use `! empty()` or `!== FALSE` instead:

```
$this->input->cookie('xtrcook') !== FALSE // evals to TRUE if the cookie exists
```

The whole thing:

```
<?php echo form_label(form_checkbox('remember', 1, $this->input->cookie('xtrcook') !== FALSE).' Auto-login in future.', 'remember'); ?>
```

It *is* a bit complicated still, might be easier to pass on the `form_label()` function and just write this:

```
<label>
    <?php echo form_checkbox('remember', 1, $this->input->cookie('xtrcook') !== FALSE); ?>
    Auto-login in future
</label>
```

Comment: No the cookie is only to remember the username just in case the user wants the system to remember it when they logout and return back to the login page

Comment: OK well that was more of an "aside", how did you make out with the rest?

Comment: There was a syntax error with this it says <?php echo form_label(form_checkbox('remember', 1, $this->input->cookie('xtrcook') !== FALSE)).' Auto-login in future.', 'remember'); ?>

Comment: You're right - I had an extra `)`. I fixed the post, try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, this looks like a view, and PHP is a server-side language, meaning that once it renders the page, it's done - it won't respond to any clicks on checkboxes... You could make an AJAX call to maintain your structure, but I suggest is to check for your remember variable on the page you submit the form to, and then set the cookie if needed.